# What process is resurrecting mysqld?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I'm following [this guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) to reset my mysql root password (I'm on ubuntu).
When I kill the mysqld process, it immediately gets resurrected. The parent process ID is 1.

How can I find what keeps resurrecting mysqld?

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql    30136     1  0 07:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     30295 30274  0 07:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
$ kill -9 30136
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql    30302     1  2 07:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     30404 30274  0 07:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
$
```

Comment: I found that doing `stop mysql` or `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` will bring it down for good (use `start` to start it back up, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses upstart:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

For future reference:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting

Answer (score 0):

You already found your answer - but for the sake of clarity.

You should try not to kill daemons or processes which are working okay - and you should certainly try and avoid kill -9.  There is usually always a way to request daemons to stop gracefully which allow them to tidy up.

Kill on it's own (e.g. `kill 30136` in your case) can sometimes correctly stop a process, but it depends on the process in question and what signals it is looking for.

Comment: The kill order was from mysql own website ...